# Getting ip address instead of hostname from gethostbyname function from InetAddress class of java

Tags: java, dns, network-programming

How is it possible to get the IP-Address from the `gethostbyname` function from the `InetAddress` class in java ? With the following code I am not getting the hostname from the local machine's ip adrress.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

class GetHost{

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

        String hostIp=args[0];
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostIp);
        String host = addr.getHostName();
        if(host.endsWith(".local"))
        {
            int lenght=host.length() ;
            System.out.print(""+host.substring(0,lenght-6));

        }
        else
            System.out.print(host);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Somebody told me that my machines dns is broken. So if so how to configure it then?

Comment: What *are* you getting?

Comment: `getByName(String host)`
Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name.  
It does not get the host's name given the ip address.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the hosts file with a line like this?

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

In your code getByName will return an InetAddress with the IP address but no hostname. When you call getHostName it will try to get the host name within the InetAddress object, and if it does not exist, the function carries out a reverse lookup address.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29)

If your hosts file is not updated with the IP you are passing a reverse DNS query will be sent out. I assume there is no DNS server with the name and address of your host, so you need to have th hosts file updated. In linux, it is in /etc/hosts. In Windows, it is located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

BTW, you can also use:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost()
```

But you will have the same problem without the proper entry in hosts file.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
private InetAddress getIP() throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        NetworkInterface ni;
        while (nis.hasMoreElements()) {
            ni = nis.nextElement();
            if (!ni.isLoopback() && ni.isUp()) {
                for (InterfaceAddress ia : ni.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                    if (ia.getAddress().getAddress().length == 4) {
                        return ia.getAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This code returns the local ip address of the pc. A simple change to getHostName should work.

Comment: No I want to get hostname of machine from its local ip. So my java code not returning me hostname. It will returning the same ip which I supplied to it.

Comment: In networking (LAN) a computer's host name is its ip. NAT is a whole different story... there is the family's/house's ip and then there are LAN ips for the connected devices on the router. Eg. my local ip is 192.168.1.2 my host name via nat is 192.168.1.2.tpg.com.au or something close to that.

Comment: @Sanket Ok, I believe I understand you know. If you wan't to get another computer's host name that computer has to tell you it you can't just grab it.

Comment: But code which I posted above is working on my friend's machine and not on mine so I am curies why so?

Comment: i.e code is returning hostname of machine from its ip

Comment: @Sanket Have you enabled port forwarding? Have you disabled their/your firewall?

Comment: @Sanket oh, thats odd. You should be able to see all devices on your router. Have you got any fancy settings enabled in your NET-BIOS' LAN tab? And even on lan some computers still have their firewalls blocking that. Eg. on windows their are firewall settings for both lan and nat. EDIT: try using my code and add an if statement checking if it's the same ip then get the hostname.

Comment: Look what I want is ? getting computer's hotname from its ip in a local area network.
I am giving local ip as input to my program and it is finding hostname of that computer.

Comment: @Sanket I understand exactly what you want. But there are limitation set by computers, routers and all that, these limitations are different everywhere. And what is the input of args[0] is it valid? Have you checked the pure output of address.getHostName()? Does it contain any characters after .local? (Eg. could be a space there, use .trim()). Does the if get called or the else? look at your condition. Also if your input is an ip why are you using getbyname()?

Comment: Ya I checked all that.

Comment: @Sanket Ok, must be something wrong with your router setup. Have you tried resetting your router's settings? I can't think of anything else that's wrong.

Comment: @Sanket I think I found your dns' issue: ` In order to resolve these IP's to host names, your machine needs a DNS that has entries for these machines, or to have them in its local hosts file; your machine isn't actually asking the remote machine for its name when you do this call so it won;t be able to find it out without help from one of its usual name resolution paths.

It works for me, because my local DNS really does have entries for all the machines on my network, resolving their host names to ip addresses and vice-versa. ` Rob Levine in topic: find-dns-hostname-from-ip-address-in-lan

Comment: please tell me the link of website or post that code here

Comment: @Sanket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002924/find-dns-hostname-from-ip-address-in-lan?rq=1           There isn't code just an explanation of what is wrong with your router not code.